# Dates sort mysql results

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I have a structure of database as it's shown in image. And I want to have the result of one column.

I have tried to do ORDER BY start, end but it didn't work in that way.

[image]

Comment: what if one of the dates is duplicated ?

Comment: Then there should be shown both of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from 
(
    select `start` as date from your_table
    union all
    select `end` from your_table
) tmp
order by date
```

Comment: How to solve it in php? I don't want to change database structure.

Comment: You don't need to change the DB. Just execute this query to get the results

Comment: Take a PHP/MySQL tutorial for that. That is very basic knowledge and you won't get far without a tutorial.

Comment: As I see this result in database is temporary, right? Then how can I select temporary result from database? It doesn't exist?

Comment: How do you select **existing** data? You make a query which returns the columns you want, filtered the way you want. The query above is nothing else. It just transforms the data a little bit while selecting.

Comment: So as I manage the solution would be:

$sql = "SELECT start, end as date FROM your_table ORDER BY date";

Comment: No, the solution would be `$sql = "select * from 
(
    select start, ...` and in PHP you can read the column named `date` from the result.